# " error in your SQL syntax .. near 'key' "

Tags: php, mysql

i get an error while executing this particular php script and i have no clue what could possibly be wrong with it.

Error code: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key='value'' at line 1

Php code:

```
<?php 
include("includes/onbowlconnect.php");

$key = $_GET['key'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bowlvalidkeys WHERE key='$key'") or die (mysql_error());

$result = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($result == 1)
{
    echo 'GameIDkey was succesfully validated !';
}
else
{   
    echo 'GameIDkey is not valid , please try again';
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me out here ?

Thanks!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`key` is reserved [mysql keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

use backticks around key this

```
 SELECT * FROM bowlvalidkeys WHERE `key` ='$key'
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

key is reserved mysql words

use this

```
$key = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bowlvalidkeys WHERE `key`='$key'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bowlvalidkeys WHERE 'key'='$key'")
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because "key" is a reserved word in MySQL. You should either change the name of the column or scape it in the query 'key' = '$key'.

Also, be sure to sanitize your $_GET variable or you will be vulnerable to SQL injections attacks.